# Where do I get the admob jar?

Tags: android, admob

I'm sure this is a stupid question, but I can't find a link anywhere and their wiki just says "Copy the AdMob Jar file into that libs directory." but not where to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register at http://www.admob.com/register/.

Then after activating your account, you need to config one application in your acccount. After that against that application Admob will provide you the Android SDK for Admob
containing admob.jar and working example (LunarLander).

Comment: So I have to publish the app without admob, then add it, then I can implement admob?

Comment: Ah I found it. Gotta add it as http:// for unpublished apps. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

There is a much simpler way for obtaining the AdMob SDK - just download it from

[Google AdMob Ads SDK Downloads](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download)

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler way is to go to :
Google AdMob Ads SDK Downloads.You will get the latest copy of Google AdMob  SDK.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Mobile Ads SDK for Android is now a part of the Google Play services platform.

It is no longer available as a standalone SDK.

[All the versions of available jars can be found here.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Use This Link
[Android addmob sdk](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download?csw=1#downloadandroid)

Download and unzip and you will get the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Latest AdMob Sdk Jar file:-

GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar ([Click to Download](https://smsoip.googlecode.com/git-history/Cherry_latest/install-admob/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the Google Admob library for Android just hit the link you will get it in few seconds:

[Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android 6.4.1:](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/scriptDownload/Google-AdMob-Ads-SDK-for-Android-Download-76896.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
```