# Android admob with AIDE

Tags: android, admob, metadata, aide-ide

I'm trying to incorporate ads into my app with a program called [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui). It's an IDE on mobile phone. When I'm doing that I'm getting an error with the meta data.

```
no resources found that match the value at value "@integer/google_play_services_version"
```

Now I never loaded the admob SDK into the app because it says it's automatically in the Google play services...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

AIDE uses a mini field version of the Android SDK. As such it excludes utilities such as the addmob libraries. Follow the steps in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868824/where-do-i-get-the-admob-jar) to add addmob services along with a complete version of the android SDK.

As an alternative you can [download the JARs here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk.htm).